# Identifying outliers from binned data

Tags: regression, outliers

I have binned data (x-axis) that I've plotted against frequency (y-axis) to see the distribution of the bins and I got this scatterplot:-
[image]

The bins are arranged from the lowest to the highest. As you can see, in terms of frequency, most of my bins follows a curve like fit with certain points existing above it. I want to be able to identify the points that exist above the curve like fit (so the points that you can see individually and that aren't part of a massive blue blur) but as you can see most of my points lie within that blue blur, meaning any form of regression I perform will just result in a curve that goes through it. What's the best way to model the data so that I can identify these outliers (i.e. bins that are of high frequency). The other alternative idea I had was arranging the data from highest frequency to lowest and then plotting a curve (which looks like an exponential curve) but then I run into the problem of choosing at which point I cut off all the other values.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this exercise?  What do you intend to do once you have identified some special bins in this manner?

Comment: The bins represent a mass range. They basically represent fragments of compounds or ions that have been produced through experimental lab work. I just need to identify which of these bins are of significance and from that try and determine what they are (i.e. whether it's like a CO2 fragment etc)

Comment: So what you're really trying to do is detect signals above a background of noise, rather than to fit any kind of curve or model to the distribution (which itself is not of any interest). In particular, your problem--although couched in terms of bins here--is not really one about histograms at all, which opens up the possibility of using non-histogram based procedures (such as kernel density estimates). Do you have measurements of individual masses or are these binned data the only values you have available? Can you say more about the nature of any measurement error?

Comment: Effectively yeah detect signals above a background of noise (although I thought it'd just be easier to try and fit some kind of curve) but yeah. I do have a measure of individual masses yes as well as the median of the masses binned. The measurement error I cannot provide any information about I'm afraid.